# Peracetic acid as a sanitizer?

Tags: sanitizer

My friend got Paracetic Acid from his LHM store (they only had that and alcohol 70 there).

Is it a non-rinse sanitizer? How good is it?

Wikipedia says it corrodes metals, so no go for the crown caps?

Does it have any other applications (thinking cleaner).

Anything else he should know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's nasty stuff. Handle with gloves! Paracetic Acid comes in several concentrations if you have the 5% Paracetic Acid solution then you should shoot for 1% of the solution in your volume of water. So 1L would need 10ml of parasafe and then scale up or down from there.

Honestly I'd skip it, and make your own sanitizer. In a pinch where I'm out of starsan I use 1oz bleach and 1oz vinegar in 5 gal water. Make sure the vinegar is fully mixed before the bleach is added. Give it a couple minutes contact time but is considered no rinse.

This solution was actually proposed in a podcast by the maker of StarSan, Relevant links: http://www.homebrewtalk.com/wiki/index.php/Homemade_No_Rinse_Sanitizer

Comment: Bleach is fine to use, but is definitely not "no rinse".

Comment: Actually at that concentration it is no rinse. Many brewers rinse because they are afraid of the possibility of off flavors, but it isn't necessary. http://www.homebrewtalk.com/wiki/index.php/Homemade_No_Rinse_Sanitizer

Comment: Wow, I stand corrected!

Comment: +1 Note though that the original recipe calls for 1oz each of bleach and vinegar in 5 gal, not 1tbsp. 1tbsp is 1/2 fl.oz - does it work at half-concentration?

Comment: My mistake will correct.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer to the question but an important safety comment, to the chap who adds vinegar to bleach. That is how chlorine is made. Chlorine is the first gas used as a poison gas in WW1. Please dont do it.

Answer (score 0):

Bleach causes pit-rusting on stainless steel, which is a perfect environment to harbour beerstone.  Do not use bleach on stainless steel when brewing.